# Summing two ordered arrays of accumulative object values over time

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to sum accumulatives values over time of two arrays, seems simple, but here's what complicates it: there might be missing dates from one of them.

When one has a value for a date and the other doesn't, we sum together that value that exists from one array and the last-seen (previous) value for a date of the other array (The example I give demonstrates this better).

Example, given two arrays of objects where in data2 there's a value for a date that data1 doesn't have:

```
var data1 = [
    {date: "30-08-2019", value: 1},
    {date: "03-09-2019", value: 2},
    {date: "04-09-2019", value: 3}
]

var data2 = [
    {date: "30-08-2019", value: 1},
    {date: "02-09-2019", value: 2},
    {date: "03-09-2019", value: 3},
    {date: "04-09-2019", value: 4}
]
```

I want the result of summing these two together (data1 + data2) to be:

```
var result = [
    {date: "30-08-2019", value: 2}, //{date: "30-08-2019", value: 1} + {date: "30-08-2019", value: 1}
    {date: "02-09-2019", value: 3}, //{date: "30-08-2019", value: 1} + {date: "02-09-2019", value: 2}
    {date: "03-09-2019", value: 5}, //{date: "03-09-2019", value: 2} + {date: "03-09-2019", value: 3}
    {date: "04-09-2019", value: 7}  //{date: "04-09-2019", value: 3} + {date: "04-09-2019", value: 4}
]
```

Since both arrays are ordered, the approach I thought was looping the array with more data and sum it with the values of the array with less data, keeping track of what are the last date values that the smaller data gives, like this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < biggerData.length; i++){

    //both have values for a date that exists the in bigger date array, so we sum them together
    if(smallerData[i][biggerData[i].date]){
       biggerData[i].value+=smallerData[i][biggerData[i].date];
       lastValue = smallerData[i][biggerData[i].date];

    //array with less data has a missing date, then sum the last saved value it gave
    }else{
       biggerData[i].value+=lastValue;
    }
}
```

There's a problem with this approach, what if the smaller array has a date that the bigger one doesn't? That value one won't be added to the final result in this case.

When going more further than this I started to loop one array like I showed before and then I loop over the other one to get the missing dates, but this just seems too complex and inefficient. I'm pretty sure there's a solution for doing this in one loop (or even not using loops at all).

I'm asking if anybody can figure out a better solution for this, I'm making this in JavaScript.

Comment: I made a slight edit to the language which I think clarifies your desired behaveiour. Please revert if I'm mistaken.

Comment: I’d start by extracting _all_ the dates from both arrays first of all, and place them into a new result array. Then loop over _that_, that ensures you cover _all_ relevant dates.

Comment: `.concat()` + _"javascript group array of objects by property"_

Comment: @Andreas grouping them by property won't do the job, I want to "sum together that value that exists from one array and the last-seen (previous) value for a date of the other array". Doing group by it will just put together common dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a bunch of helper variables and converted the dates into an easily sortable format. Going through all existing dates in chronological order makes it quite easy to keep track of the accumulated value for each array. The sorting is the inefficient part, since the rest has linear complexity. You could optimize the sorting by taking advantage of the fact that both arrays are already sorted, but I was too lazy to do this here :)

```
// Turn '30-08-2019' into '2019-08-30'
const getSortableDate = (dateString) => dateString.split('-').reverse().join('-');

// Enable direct lookup of values
const mapDatesToValues = (data) => {
    const dates = {};
    data.forEach((item) => {
        dates[getSortableDate(item.date)] = item.value;
    });
    return dates;  
};

// Source data
const data1 = [
    {date: "30-08-2019", value: 1},
    {date: "03-09-2019", value: 2},
    {date: "04-09-2019", value: 3}
];

const data2 = [
    {date: "30-08-2019", value: 1},
    {date: "02-09-2019", value: 2},
    {date: "03-09-2019", value: 3},
    {date: "04-09-2019", value: 4}
];

// values for direct lookup
const dates1 = mapDatesToValues(data1);
const dates2 = mapDatesToValues(data2);

// Chronological order for all existing dates
const allDatesOrdered = Object.keys({ ...dates1, ...dates2 }).sort();

// Helper variables:
let acc1 = 0; // Accumulated value while iterating through data1
let acc2 = 0; // Accumulated value while iterating through data2

let existsIn1;
let existsIn2;

let value1; // Current value while iterating through data1
let value2; // Current value while iterating through data2

allDatesOrdered.forEach((date) => {
    existsIn1 = dates1.hasOwnProperty(date);
    existsIn2 = dates2.hasOwnProperty(date);

    value1 = dates1[date];
    value2 = dates2[date];

    // Remember accumulated values
    if (existsIn1) {
        acc1 = value1;
    }
    if (existsIn2) {
        acc2 = value2;
    }

    if (existsIn1 && existsIn2) {
        console.log('sum for', date, 'is', value1 + value2, '(found in both arrays)');
    } else {
        if (existsIn1) {
            console.log('sum for', date, 'is', value1 + acc2, '(only found in data1)');
        } else {
            console.log('sum for', date, 'is', value2 + acc1, '(only found in data2)');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a good answer and does the job right, but it's a shame that there has to be so much work around the date sorting

Comment: @Anamoreira I guess that's because of DD-MM-YYYY strings - it's inevitable to compare two of them at some point. No matter how much this is optimized, code that inspects such a string needs to be somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way of going through this quite efficiently, but I converted the dates to millisecond timestamps due to beeing more suitable in the context I'm using this. Because of this change I'm not going to put my answer as the correct one.

@timotgl answer does it without converting date values so therefore I'm marking it the correct answer, although the solution also contains a change in the date format (that didn't helped me in my case but can help others).

I'm basically doing a zip function, going through both arrays and the merged result is being pushed in a result array of objects in one go.

```
data1.forEach((item) => {
    item.date = new Date(item.date).getTime();
});

data2.forEach((item) => {
    item.date = new Date(item.date).getTime();
});

let mergedPortfolio = [], //final array of objects

        data1Idx = 0, //indexes for each array of objects
        data2Idx = 0,

        data1Last, //keeping track of last values
        data2Last,

        date1, //current date value
        date2,

        value1,//current value
        value2;    

while(data1Idx < data1.length || data2Idx < data2.length){

    //both arrays exist
    if(data1Idx < data1.length && data2Idx < data2.length){

        date1 = data1[data1Idx].date;
        date2 = data2[data2Idx].date;

        value1 = data1[data1Idx].value;
        value2 = data2[data2Idx].value;

        if(date1 < date2){

            mergedPortfolio.push({date: date1, value: value1+data2Last});

            data1Last = value1;
            ++data1Idx;

        }else if(data1[data1Idx].date === data2[data2Idx].date){
            mergedPortfolio.push({date: date1, value: value1+value2})

            data1Last = value1;
            data2Last = value2;

            ++data1Idx;
            ++data2Idx;

        }else if(data1[data1Idx].date > data2[data2Idx].date){

            mergedPortfolio.push({date: date2, value: data1Last+value2});

            data2Last = value2;
            ++data2Idx;

        }

    //Working through the remaining items in one data1 array
    }else if(data1Idx < data1.length){

        date1 = data1[data1Idx].date;

        value1 = data1[data1Idx].value;

        mergedPortfolio.push({date: date1, value: value1+data2Last});

        data1Last = value1;
        ++data1Idx;

    //Working through the remaining items in the data2 array
    }else if(data2Idx > data2.length){

        date2 = data2[data2Idx].date;

        value2 = data2[data2Idx].value;

        mergedPortfolio.push({date: date2, value: value2+data1Last});

        data2Last = value1;
        ++data2Idx;

    }

}
```